# PHP Foreach SQL, INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only inserting last query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update

PHP, using PDO to update SQL database, is only updating last query with a random number for the warehouse_id into phpmyadmin.

```
function updateWarehouses(){


    global $tvHost, $handler, $apiRequestCall, $sqlError;


    $apiUpdateWarehouses = apiRequestCall("GET", $tvHost, "Product?pageNumber=1");
    $updates = 0;
    foreach($apiUpdateWarehouses['List'] as $c){
        foreach($c['PerWarehouseInventory'] as $i) {

            try {
                    $sql = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO tv_warehouse (warehouse_id, code) VALUES (:warehouse_id, :code) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE warehouse_id=:warehouse_id, code=:code");
                    echo "<br>".$i['WarehouseID']." ".$i['WarehouseCode'];
                    $sql->execute([
                    ':warehouse_id' => $i['WarehouseID'],
                    ':code' => $i['WarehouseCode']]
                    );
                    $updates++;
                }
            catch(Exception $er) {
                    sqlError($er, $table);
                    die();
            }
            } 
        }
        echo "<br>".$updates." warehouses updated.";
    }
```

I have printed out the variables being entered you can't see with the echo statement:

Displayed on page when script is run (WarehouseID WarehouseCode)

```
3.5284454726114E+18 Demo
3.5284455793003E+18 Temp Rework
3.5950682694297E+18 TL-Shipments
3.5897270029153E+18 TL-Supplier
3.4684900596836E+18 WH1
5 warehouses updated.
```

The only one being entered is warehouse_id = 2147483647  and warehouse_code = WH1

WH1 is correct but where did 2147483647 come from? and why isn't the rest of them being entered?

Table format:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Data`.`tv_warehouse`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Data`.`tv_warehouse` (
  `code` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` INT(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`warehouse_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

JSON:

```
{
    "List": [
        {

            "PerWarehouseInventory": [
                {
                    "WarehouseID": 3528445472611403000,
                    "WarehouseCode": "Demo",
                },
                {
                    "WarehouseID": 3528445579300286000,
                    "WarehouseCode": "Temp Rework",
                },
                {
                    "WarehouseID": 3595068269429729300,
                    "WarehouseCode": "TL-Shipments",
                },
                {
                    "WarehouseID": 3589727002915314000,
                    "WarehouseCode": "TL-Supplier",
                },
                {
                    "WarehouseID": 3468490059683634700,
                    "WarehouseCode": "WH1",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help on why this is doing this would be great I am using "json_decode($data, true);"

If that helps,

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something useful for you, "2147483647" is the maximum size of Int.

Try to use BigInt or something higher.

If you have just one result, it's because your ID is your INT, and your ID is always equals to 2147483647, so you always have updates.

Here is the link :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Thanks, I clearly need to do some more research which each do, but yes that worked.